# Adding users from directory to contacts

Tags: c#, google-contacts-api, google-directory-api, google-people-api

I am trying to add users from Gsuite Directory as a contact for all users in the directory.

```
var credential = GetCredentialForUser(User.PrimaryEmail);

                // Create Drive API service.
                var peopleService = new PeopleServiceService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
                {
                    HttpClientInitializer = credential
                });
                PeopleResource.ListDirectoryPeopleRequest peopleRequest =
                 peopleService.People.ListDirectoryPeople();
                peopleRequest.ReadMask = "names,emailAddresses,addresses,phoneNumbers";
                peopleRequest.Sources = PeopleResource.ListDirectoryPeopleRequest.SourcesEnum.DIRECTORYSOURCETYPEDOMAINPROFILE;
                peopleRequest.PageSize = 1000;
                //peopleRequest.SortOrder = (PeopleResource.ConnectionsResource.ListRequest.SortOrderEnum)1;
                var res = peopleRequest.Execute();
                var list = peopleService.ContactGroups.List().Execute();
                //var directoryPeople = peopleService.People.ListDirectoryPeople().Execute();
                var person = res.People.FirstOrDefault();
                foreach (var label in list.ContactGroups)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(label.ResourceName);
                }
                var all = list.ContactGroups.Where(s => s.Name== "myContacts").FirstOrDefault();
                var members = peopleService.ContactGroups.Members.Modify(new ModifyContactGroupMembersRequest() { ResourceNamesToAdd = new List<string> { person.ResourceName }, ResourceNamesToRemove = new List<string> {  } }, all.ResourceName).Execute();
```

I am receiving an exception

```
{"Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError\r\nResource name \"people/XXXYYYY\" is not a valid contact person resource. [400]\r\nErrors [\r\n\tMessage[Resource name \"people/XXXYYYY\" is not a valid contact person resource.] Location[ - ] Reason[badRequest] Domain[global]\r\n]\r\n"}
```

Does that mean we cannot add a user using people api from directory as a contact, if so what is the best way to do it in batch? clearing all contacts and adding new users from directory?

Comment: The error is saying that the resource is not correct. Have you tried using the `try this` on the api reference page?

Comment: I am adding a user from directory, just want to know if this supported or how can I create a user from directory as contact?

Comment: Have you tried creating contacts with the profile email and then adding them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to add a profile to a contact group. You can only add contacts to contact groups. So you should just create a contact with the profile email.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my function to set up a batch request to create a contact.

Convert all of the directory contacts to Person then send it in with a BatchRequest.
At the end execute the batch request to create the contacts.

Make sure to include a primary email address on Person. Note that I check for ClientData - that is where I store my app name and AD's user unique id to track what my app added.

```
    public Person CreateContact(BatchRequests batchRequest, Person contact, List<string> errors)
    {

        if (contact.EmailAddresses == null || 
            contact.EmailAddresses.Count == 0 || 
            !contact.EmailAddresses.Any(e => e.Metadata.Primary == true))
            throw new Exception("Primary Email Address Not Found.");

        try
        {
            if (!batchRequest.BatchCreateContactsRequest.Contacts.Any(c => c.ContactPerson.ClientData == contact.ClientData))
            {
                ContactToCreate contactToCreate = new ContactToCreate();
                contactToCreate.ContactPerson = contact;
                batchRequest.BatchCreateContactsRequest.Contacts.Add(contactToCreate);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // CurrentPersonEmail is the user's email whose contacts are being modified.
            errors.Add($"Error;{CurrentPersonEmail};{ex.Message}. StackTrace:{ex.StackTrace}");
        }

        return contact;
    }
```

Once you have all the contacts ready - then execute the request (it's not the full code but I hope you get the idea how to call it):

```
    BatchCreateContactsResponse batchCreateContactsResponse = PeopleService.People.BatchCreateContacts(BatchCreateContactsRequest).Execute();
```

Comment: I also assign all users from AD to group/label in Contacts so they are grouped together.