# Where to find sample C# .NET code for Google's People API?

Tags: google-people-api

I have an installed app that uses .NET and the Contacts API.  I'm trying to convert to the People API.  I'm having trouble getting started and finding a sample that shows how to use People API with the .NET library.  For example, the samples listed under the [Peoples API documentation](https://developers.google.com/people/quickstart/js) doesn't include .NET.  Where can I find a .NET sample for the People API?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are [off-topic for Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) nowadays, but the unaccepted answer to [.NET client for the Google People API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23759400/net-client-for-the-google-people-api) should lead you there.

Comment: You can file a [feature request](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) to ask to add C# documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Start with this ;)

https://googleapis.dev/dotnet/Google.Apis.PeopleService.v1/latest/api/Google.Apis.PeopleService.v1.html

Get the nuget called Google.Apis.PeopleService.v1 https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-dotnet-client

Also, I'm sure you have seen this https://developers.google.com/people/v1/profiles
It has some .net examples.

What exactly are you trying to accomplish?
I am just about to complete converting an app that used contacts API to people API using a service account for the company.

ps. I can't copy the whole namespace in the answer hense answer with a link.

Edited: 20210608

```
        Person person = new Person();

        person.EmailAddresses = new List<EmailAddress>();
        person.EmailAddresses.Add(new EmailAddress() { Type = "work", Value = "sample@domain.com" });
        person.Names = new List<Name>();
        person.Names.Add(new Name() { FamilyName = "Lname2", GivenName = "Fname" });

        // link to peopleService code can be found in the comments
        // it's basically initializing PeopleServiceService with service account credentials
        Person retVal = peopleService.People.CreateContact(person).Execute();
```

Comment: Thanks Zunair.  Yes, I did see the namespace documentation.  I was looking for some example .NET code that showed how to do some basic operations with contacts and groups.  I'm figuring it out from the documentation, but I find some sample code very helpful, especially when getting started.  I'm syncing a Windows address book to Google contacts.

Comment: see this for service initialization https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50385783/peopleapi-error-403-google-bugs-or-not/67878094#67878094
 I'll add a small sample to create a user - I only use the Batch classes, use that if you plan to modify lots of data.

Comment: here is the link to batch request code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63598523/adding-users-from-directory-to-contacts/67877788#67877788

Comment: @Zunair, I tried to retrieve status of batch request, but seems like it is all null values. Have you tried reading Status property from PeopleResponse?

Comment: I just updated the batch request code - I didn't show how to execute the batch request :facepalm

Comment: @djacob, and I actually didn't answer you - I haven't used PeopleResponse. Since it's a batch request, we need to use the batch response classes, such as BatchCreateContactsResponse from Google.Apis.PeopleService.v1.Data